# Angular template loading if

Tags: angular

I want to make a component that either shows a loading spinner or the content. It's template looks like this

```
<ng-template  [ngIf]="loader.isLoading">
  <div class="loader">
    <div><span class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-4x"></span></div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let m of loader.messages">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template [ngIf]="!loader.isLoading">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and its called like this

```
<loader [loader]="loader">
  Now we have loaded: {{ theThingThatWasLoading }}.
</loader>
```

However, the `<ng-content>` template is rendered in all cases. Why is the `ngIf` being ignored? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try to use `*ngif="condition"` instead of `[ngIf]="condition"`

Comment: Replace your `ng-template` with`<ng-container *ngIf="true"></ng-container>`. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

> ng-template tag we are simply defining a template

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
<div class="loader" *ngIf="loader.isLoading; else content">
   <div><span class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-4x"></span></div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let m of loader.messages">{{m}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

This is also practical if you would want to show the loader on several locations within the same component template.
Otherwise, you can use `<ng-container *ngIf="condition">` for "cleaner" syntax.

Comment: I'm using this pattern a lot -- that's why I wanted to formalise it in a component. Sometimes there is just 1 thing loading. Sometimes there are several things loading in paralle; (and sometimes in sequence which was a nightmare to get RxJS to do compared to simple nested callbacks.)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Again the content tries to render before loading has finished.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Are you initiating `loader.isLoading` as `true`? Could you please add your `.ts`?

Comment: Same result with `<div class="loader" *ngIf="false; else content">`
The content doesn't show, but the console is full of errors from trying to render it before stuff has loaded.